# How to assert objects by its state (all properties values) in a Dart unit test?

Tags: dart

I have a class (with more properties than the example, of course).

How to write the following simple test? I know that equality in Dart is by object instance. How to compare the full object state? I tested with the `same` matcher as well, with no luck.

```dart
import 'package:test/test.dart';

class UnderTesting {
  var a;
  var b;
  UnderTesting({this.a, this.b});
}

void main() {
  test("compare objects", () {
    final obj1 = UnderTesting(a:1, b:2);
    final obj2 = UnderTesting(a:1, b:2);
    
    // Next will fail because it is checking if it is the same instance
    expect(obj1, equals(obj2));
  } );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the `==` operator (and should therefore also override `hashCode`) for `UnderTesting`. The documentation for `equals` tells us how to does test for equality:

> If [expected] is a [Matcher], then it matches using that. Otherwise it tests for equality using `==` on the expected value.

So you code should be something like this:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:quiver/core.dart';

class UnderTesting {
  int a;
  int b;
  UnderTesting({this.a, this.b});

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      (other is UnderTesting) ? (a == other.a && b == other.b) : false;

  @override
  int get hashCode => hash2(a, b);
}

void main() {
  test("compare objects", () {
    final obj1 = UnderTesting(a: 1, b: 2);
    final obj2 = UnderTesting(a: 1, b: 2);

    expect(obj1, equals(obj2)); // All tests passed!
  });
}
```

I can recommend the `quiver` package for making easy `hashCode` implementations: https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.core/quiver.core-library.html

Comment: I was expecting a specific matcher to compare the class state. I don't like the idea of doing it in all my model classes only for testing. Also, I don't like to modify production classes only because of testing. In fact, I concern about the side effect when these classes are used by Flutter.

Comment: You can in theory do some tricks with dart:mirrors but in the end, you should let objects specify what it means to be equal because, sometime, it is not just that simple as to just check the inner state of the object on a binary level. I would say that for model data, you should always override `==` and `hashCode` (so you can e.g. ignore internal private state if it is not important). If you are worried that this will mess up production, you do have different point of view of what equal means. In that case, you should write specific test methods in your test code which compare your objects.

Comment: Marked as right answer, but I don't like this way for testing. Dart needs better testing tools.